# Where should be the @Override notation be?

Tags: java, overriding

```
public class Occupant {

    private Position pos;

    public Occupant(Position iniPos) { 
        this.pos = iniPos; 
    } 

    public Position getPosition() { 
        return pos; 
    } 

    public void setPosition(Position newPos) { 
        this.pos = newPos; 
    } 

    public String getStringRepresentation() { 
        return " "; 
    }
}
```

I need to override getStringRepresenation in its subclass to X, here's what i wrote.

```
public class Mine extends Occupant {
    private Position pos; 

    public Mine(Position iniPos) { 
        this.pos = iniPos; 
    }

    public String getStringRepresentation() {
      return "X";
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where to use super and @Override, the class won't compile.

Comment: It wont allow me to pass public Mine(Position iniPos) { 
        this.pos = iniPos; 
    }

Comment: in the test file it has testMine = new Mine(position); i thought thats what i need to write in the class

Answer (score 1):

In front of  the sub class `Mine`'s method, you need to add `@Override` annotation.

```
@Override
public String getStringRepresentation() { 
      return "X";
}
```

And, in your sub class Constructor, you have to call super class Constructor.

```
public Mine(Position iniPos) { 
        super(iniPos); // you need to call super class constructor
        this.pos = iniPos; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The class won't compile because `Occupant` has a single constructor that takes an argument. So in the `Mine` constructor you need to call the superclass constructor. That is what the `super` keyword does when it's not used with a method name.

You don't *need* to use the `@Override` annotation [but it's recommended](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).

> When overriding a method, you might want to use the @Override annotation that instructs the compiler that you intend to override a method in the superclass. If, for some reason, the compiler detects that the method does not exist in one of the superclasses, then it will generate an error.

```
public class Mine extends Occupant {
    public Mine(Position iniPos) {
        // call super constructor
        super(iniPos);
    }

    // annotate
    @Override
    public String getStringRepresentation() {
        return "X";
    }
}
```

Note that `Mine` probably does not need another `Position` because the superclass already has one. Just pass the constructor argument on to the superclass.

Having to call the constructor yourself is just an aspect of Java inheritance. Constructors are not inherited so if the superclass doesn't have a no argument constructor you have to call one explicitly. If the superclass does have a no argument constructor and you don't make an explicit constructor call, the compiler inserts a `super();` for you.

Answer (score 0):

You use `@Override` annotation over the method you intent to override just to make sure at compile time that we are really overriding the method, also adds good amount to the readability of code.

```
@Override
public String getStringRepresentation() { 
}
```

If your method overrides one of its superclass's methods, you can invoke the overridden method through the use of the keyword `super`.

Now you want to access the `getStringRepresentation` of your `superclass` you can use `super.getStringRepresentation()`